# bind(socket1,(struct sockaddr *)&net,sizeof(net)); - не понял второй аргумент

Tags: c, сеть

Почему в строке `bind(socket1,(struct sockaddr *)&net,sizeof(net));`, а именно, во втором аргументе нужно указывать что-то непонятное для меня: `(struct sockaddr *)&net`.

Почему я не могу просто послать имя структуры, вот так: `bind(socket1,net,sizeof(net));`?

Буду очень благодарен за объяснения :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У переменной `net` тип `sockaddr_in`, или `sockaddr_un`, или какая-то другая конкретная структура нужная для используемого протокола (суффиксы `_in`, `_in6`, `_un` и т.п. соответствуют `AF_INET`, `AF_INET6`, `AF_UNIX` и прочим типам адресов).

А `bind` принимает параметр `const struct sockaddr *addr`. Эта структура `sockaddr` имеет "абстрактный" тип, который отличается от типа вашей `net`.

```
struct sockaddr {
    sa_family_t sa_family;   // по этому полю bind поймет какая это структура 
                             // (например sockaddr_in для AF_INET)
    char        sa_data[14]; // сам адрес, формат зависит от типа адреса
}
```

Поэтому нельзя передать `&net`, надо делать явный каст в тип `const struct sockaddr *`. (Достаточно сделать каст к `struct sockaddr *`, `const` добавится неявным кастом).